# How to move closures forever

Tags: rust

I'm designing a little struct that runs closures for me and I can set them to stop:

```
pub fn run(&self, f: Box<dyn Fn()>) {
    let should_continue = self.should_continue.clone();

    self.run_thread = Some(std::thread::spawn(move || {
        while should_continue.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
            //f should run fast so `should_continue` is readed frequently
            f();
        }
    }));
}
```

as you can see, I'm passing `Fn` in a box, which gives me an error about Box not being shareable between threads. Actually, I don't care about fn once I pass it to this function `run`, so I wanted to move the closure to this function, since I'll not use it anymore. I cannot mark `Fn` as send because the `f` that I'm gonna actually pass does not implement `Send`.

So, how can I move a closure completely?

```
//move this closure to inside of run
self.run(||{});
```

Answer (score 8):

Having a buildable reproduction case rather than code with random unprovided dependencies is useful [so here's what I understand of your code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=122abd4750965d6fd277424c66132b48).

The error I get is that the `dyn Fn` can not be **sent** between threads which is very different than **shared**:  while there are many things which can not be *shared* (`Sync`) between threads (they can only be used from one thread at a time) there are also things which must remain on their original thread at all time. `Rc` for instance, is not `Send`, because it's not a thread-safe reference-counted pointer sending an `Rc` to a different thread would break its guarantees, therefore that's not allowed.

`dyn Fn` is opaque and offers no real guarantee as to what it's doing internally except for, well, being callable multiple times. So as far as the compiler is concerned it could close over something which isn't `Send` (e.g. a reference to a `!Sync` type, or an `Rc`, ...), which means the compiler assumes the `Fn` isn't `Send` either.

The solution is simple: just define `f: Box<dyn Fn() + Send>`, this way within `run` you guarantee that the function can, in fact, be sent between threads; and the caller to `run` will get an error if they're trying to send a function which can not be sent.

[demo](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b45e7d59bcc554e9f2993520e8de99b4)

`run_ok` uses a trivial closure, there is no issue with sending it over. `run_not_ok` closes over an `Rc`, and the function therefore doesn't compile (just uncomment it to see). `run_ok2` is the same function as `run_not_ok` using an `Arc` instead of the `Rc`, and compiles fine.